# How does inFamous 2 decide if you were good or evil in the previous game?

Tags: infamous-2

The way I understand it, is that it takes the information from your accumulated trophies, but what if I've beaten inFamous-1 as both evil and good and have both of the relavent trophies for doing so? How does it decide then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it looks for savegames from the previous game.
When starting a new game with an Infamous save present, you'd have the option to start the game as good or evil, depending on the progress present in the savegames on your machine. So if, for example, you only have a save where you finished as evil, you'll have the option to start Infamous 2 as evil. If you have saves for both endings, you'd have an option to start as good or evil, etc.

You always have the option to start from scratch. Also, there are certain other bonuses for a present save game, for example, you get an energy cores bonuses if you collected enough shards in the previous games.

Comment: Edit: removed comment as it should be a question.

Comment: There is a an energy core bonus for collecting 25% of the shards, another energy core for collecting 50% and a 1000xp bonus for any game completion, good or bad. Also, the game will also reference karma decisions made in the previous game, for example, when collecting a certain dead drop in Infamous 2 I heard someone describe my karma choice in the doctors rooftop rescue mission in Infamous 1.

Comment: As an example, in the "Past Decisions" side mission, if you destroyed the Ray Sphere in Infamous 1, the woman will thank you for saving her grandmother, kiss you on the cheek, then the mission ends immediately, awarding you 20 XP. On the other hand, if you used the Ray Sphere on Empire City, the same woman will threaten Cole, then the Militia she hired will try to kill you. If you defeat them, you get 20 XP.